# Filling a curve towards toward the top of the plot

Tags: plotting, filling

I have a curve. If I want to color fill or shade, not towards axis but upward form the curve, what command can I use?

Answer (score 5):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Top]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> 0.5]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 Filling -> 0.5,
 FillingStyle ->
  {Directive[Opacity[0.5], Orange],
   Directive[Opacity[0.5], Yellow]},
 GridLines -> {None, {0.5}},
 GridLinesStyle -> Dashed
```

[image]